# What is the complexity of this piece of code

Tags: c, complexity-theory

I had to determinate big O complexity of this piece of code.
I thought the answer is nlogn but apparently its n. Can anyone help explain why that is so?

```
void funct(int n)
{
    for (int i = n; i > 0; i /= 2)
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            printf("%d\n", j%2);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's geometric progression
The first time the inner loop is executed **n** times.
The second time it is executed **n/2** times.
etc...
So we have the sequence:
n + n/2 + n/4 + ... + 1
so the final formula is:

```
n*(1 - (1/2)^(log n))/(1/2)
```

which is equivalent to **n**

Comment: It's a little more complex, if you take into account that `n` is not a power of 2, but the result will be the same. Still, finally someone with the right approach and without arm-waving :-)

Answer (score 1):

Look these can be solved  using Double Sigma's :
Let `$` represents [sigma](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/sigma-notation.html).
so this problem is :

`$(i=n downto 0 by a factor of 2 )$(j=0 to i-1) 1`

where `1` represent a  unit cost

now for inner sigma its sum of `1` `i` times that is  = i

now problem is 
`$(i=n downto 1 by a factor of 2 ) i`

which is sum of `i` values i.e. `n+n/2+n/4+...+1(when n/2^x=1 or after log(n) terms)+0`

or 
`n*(1+1/2+.....log(n) terms)`

which is a convergent [Geometric progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression). and the result will be `n*(1 - (1/2)^(log n))/(1/2)` i.e `O(n)`

Answer (score 0):

The outer loop, as I'm sure you can see is executed `log(n)` times. The inner loop is executed on average `log(n)/2` times.  So the `printf` statement is executed `log(n) * (log(n) / 2)` times which equals `n / 2`. So the complexity of the code is O(n).

Comment: `i /= 2` Outer loop is executer `log(n)` times

Comment: @kostek Oh, I didn't catch that. Thanks. Updating now.

Comment: I agree with the result O(n), but the inner loop is *not* being executed `log(n) / 2` times. If someone uses the "on average" argument in O-notation questions, the argument is wrong in most cases. The iterations for the inner loop have to be analyzed as a function of the iteration of the outer loop and the *whole* term has to be analyzed. You are lucky the result is correct.

Comment: And `log(n) * (log(n) / 2)` is *not* equal to `n/2`.

Comment: @mastov, why not the _inner_ loop will execute `n` times?

Comment: @rakeb.void: The *inner* loop runs `i` times for every iteration of the *outer* loop. How often that is in total, you can see in Ihar Drozdov's answer.